# Arrange arrays elements with javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a function that will arrange points in a table like as shown in the image:

[image]

Code I need to modify is:

```
var rowsCount = 7;
var heightTable = 700;
var rowHeight = 100;

//an array with divs with elements, every element has a top and left position
var arrayOfDivs = [({topPosition : 99, leftPosition: 100}),({topPosition : 150, leftPosition: 400}),({topPosition : 578, leftPosition: 10})];

//so here create a function that will create arrays = rowCount, so here we will need 7 arrays and arrange elements from arrayOfDivs into new arrays


function arrangeInNewArrays (rowsCont,heightTable,rowHeight) {
    var j=0;
    for i=0 {
        if (arrayOfDivs.topPosition[0] > rowHeight*j < rowHeight){
              var array+j = array+j+arrayOfDivs[i];
        }else {
              i++,j++
        }
    }

    print arrayofDivs[i];
}
```

Any suggestions? How can I arrange points by row...

Please help me to do that///

CODE: http://jsfiddle.net/sYq9S/9/

Comment: arrange points from table by rows in arrays

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sYq9S/9/

Comment: someone put a bounty on this question before I answer it :D this is not going to be answered soon, I worked with something very similar a couple of months ago

Comment: I'm leaving work right now, will go over it once I get home and break my fast

Comment: The idea of a js fiddle is a _somewhat_ working example of your code. Not jibberish.

Comment: ok, we will wait for you:)

Comment: I don't understand the question. I can only help you to fix syntactic errors: remove rounded brackets in your array [{topPosition : 99, leftPosition: 100},{...},...]. Your for loop is wrong. See here for the syntax: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: What do you mean "arrange points by row"? Do you want to group all points by `topPosition`?

Comment: I want to group (see image) all point in one array, after that to create as many new arrays as many rows has table and in this example in first array is 3 elements, in second array is 4 elements ... ... I want to extract points (on image) from rows to new array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use something like this:

```
var ROW_HEIGHT = 100; //assume 100px, but you can change this
var rowsCount = 7;

var rows = [];
for(var i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++) {
    rows[i] = [];
}

for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfDivs.length; i++) {
   var position = arrayOfDivs[i];

   //The assumption is that the table starts at position 0. If not, you will
   //have to subtract the table's top position from topPosition
   var rowNumber = Math.floor(position.topPosition / ROW_HEIGHT);
   rows[rowNumber].push(position);
}
```

This will end up grouping divs into rows, based on their `topPosition`. So anything that with `0 <= topPosition < 100` will be in `row[0]` (first row), anything with `100 <= topPosition < 200` will be in `row[1]` (second row) and so on.

You can then iterate over these and position them based on the `leftPosition`.

This won't necessarily give you `7` rows though because it depends on the `topPosition` of each element. So if you don't have anything that has a `topPosition` such that `600 <= topPosition < 600` then there won't be anything in the seventh row.

If you want to sort by `leftPosition` within each of the rows, you can do this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++) {
    rows[i].sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.leftPosition - b.leftPosition;
    });
}
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u58k6/).

Comment: please show in one jsfiddle, I dont see what function return here. THANKS

Comment: @MarkWest The function returns `rows`.

Comment: so this function will create 7 new arrays with elements inside with top and left row[1]({topPosition: top, leftPosition: left} { etc. ...}, ... ... ... How to arrange it after that every new created array row[i] by left position inside array?

Comment: can you post jsfiddle to see what is exactly the result

Comment: yes this is it, but i find that if I add elements to arrayOfDivs they want to show in output... var arrayOfDivs = [({topPosition : 99, leftPosition: 100, km:44.54}) ... km won't show in output ...

Comment: where I need to add this for left position, after what code, canyou update jsfiddle ?

Comment: What do you mean by "add this for left position"? Do you mean to sort? You can add it right after the last loop.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34195/discussion-between-mark-west-and-vivin-paliath)

Comment: why when I change values this dont work, I changes with real values ... : http://jsfiddle.net/u58k6/10